# FindForm and WPF

Tags: wpf, winforms

I have an application that has a WinForm(`myForm`).

In that WinForm there are a WPF UserControl(`myWPF`).

In that WPF UserControl there are a WinForm UserControl(`myWinCtrl`).

The myWinCtrl has a custom WinGrid(`myWinGrid`).

`myWinGrid` does internally a `this.FindForm()` and.... does not find `myForm`...

*Is there a way to override the `FindForm` method in order that it includes the possibility of a WPF intermediary layer?*

```
myGrid => myWinFormUC => Host => WpfUC => Host => myWinForm
```

So, I need `myGrid` finds `myWinForm`

Answer (score 1):

You could use PInvoke with [GetAncestor](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32/GetAncestor.html) to directly get the top level form containing your control.

At that point, you could compare the resulting IntPtr to the handles in each form of Application.OpenForms to find the actual Windows Forms Form instance.

---

A possible brute force approach could be to use [Control.PointToScreen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.pointtoscreen.aspx) with the center of your control, then search your Application.OpenForms for any active forms containing that point.  The tricky part would be handling if you had overlapping forms, but only one should be active, so if this is in response to a UI action, the active form at that location should be the correct form...

Comment: not works very well... GetAncenstor returns IntPtr, but this is not a good one..., also System.Windows.Forms.Integration.WindowsFormsHost does not have a "Handler" property

Comment: @Jamie Keeling: the GetControl(thisIntPtr) should be at least, a form.

Answer (score 0):

This is a sample code based on [Reed's idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4034819/1477064)

```
    private Form FindOwnerThroughHandle(Control ctrl)
    {
        var ancestorHandle = GetAncestor(ctrl.Handle, GetAncestorFlags.GA_ROOT);
        return Control.FromHandle(ancestorHandle) as Form;
    }

    private enum GetAncestorFlags : uint
    {
        // Retrieves the parent window.This does not include the owner, as it does with the GetParent function.
        GA_PARENT = 1,
        // Retrieves the root window by walking the chain of parent windows.
        GA_ROOT = 2,
        // Retrieves the owned root window by walking the chain of parent and owner windows returned by GetParent.
        GA_ROOTOWNER = 3,
    }

    [DllImport("user32.dll", ExactSpelling = true)]
    static extern IntPtr GetAncestor(IntPtr hwnd, GetAncestorFlags flags);
```